# Blamed equally with his brother

Tags: usage

I am not able to understand the grammatical structure of the following sentence though I am  able to comprehend its meaning

> He is to be blamed equally with his brother.

I looked up the meaning of **equally** and **with** but didn't find any such use as it is used here.(no other context can be provided regarding the sentence as it is just an example sentence in my grammar book)

Somebody help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a specialized grammatical structure, but just words combined with each other, each one contributing its standard meaning to comprise a full sentence. "With" means *together*, and "equally" means *the same*:

> "We blame him." (We accuse him of causing some problem)
>
> "He is blamed." (passive voice)
>
> "He is to be blamed." ("is to be" = "ought to be", as explained in
>   [BBC learning English site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv103.shtml))
>
> "He is to be blamed [together] with his brother." (*Both* brothers are
>   to be blamed)
>
> "He is to be blamed equally with his brother." (Both are to be blamed
>   in the same degree.)